# How to serve different versions of the same web app based on subdomain - CSR w/ React

Tags: reactjs, architecture

I'm currently trying to create an application that will serve a client side web application that will be mostly the same, but slightly different based on the different subdomains. For example, client1.website.com vs client2.website.com -- same base app, slightly different branding and content.

Currently, I have attempted to save this content by fetching static JSON files that contain the differences between the two sites. They are made as a normal GET call to the local server and then applied as a 'content' key in the state object of the application. The problem I am having is that I am unable to reference parts of the content because React attempts to render them before the parent application is finished applying the 'content' state.

Is this architecture the wrong way to go about things or is there a solution that I just haven't found yet?

I've posted my code below to try and show what I'm doing, I've used a third party state library to try and simplify what something like redux would do when full fleshed out:

```js
// Index.js (Contains my store)

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { StoreProvider, createStore, thunk, action } from "easy-peasy";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./pages/App";

const store = createStore({
   company: {
      contentType: "default",
      baseContent: {},
      partnerContent: {},

      setContentType: action((state, payload) => {
         state.contentType = payload;
      }),
      setContentData: action((state, payload) => {
         state[payload.type] = payload.data;
      }),

      loadContent: thunk(async (actions, payload) => {
         try {
            if (payload !== "base") {
               actions.setContentType(payload);
            }
            const partnerData = await axios.get(`content/${payload}.json`);
            const baseData = await axios.get(`content/base.json`);
            actions.setContentData({
               data: partnerData.data,
               type: "partnerContent",
            });
            actions.setContentData({
               data: baseData.data,
               type: "baseContent",
            });
         } catch (e) {
            throw e;
         }
      }),
   },
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <App />
   </StoreProvider>,
   document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```js
//App.js (Where I attempt to suspend until my data is loaded into state)

import React, { useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { useStoreActions } from "easy-peasy";

import Header from "../components/Header";
import Content from "../components/Content";

import "./App.css";

const content = "default";

const App = () => {
   const { loadContent } = useStoreActions((actions) => ({
      loadContent: actions.payforward.loadContent,
   }));

   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
         await loadContent(content);
      }

      fetchData();
   }, [loadContent]);

   return (
      <div className='App'>
         <Header />
         <Content />
      </div>
   );
};

export default App;
```

```js
//Header.js (Where I attempt to reference some URLs from the JSON file applied to my state)

import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";

const Header = () => {
   //Unable to access state because it's currently undefined until the JSON is loaded in
   const headerURLs = useStoreState(
      (state) => state.company.partnerContent.routes.header.links
   );

   return (
      <div>
         <h1>This is the Header</h1>
         {/* {headerURLs.map((url) => {
            return <p>{url}</p>;
         })} */}
      </div>
   );
};

export { Header as default };
```